# how to remove <script> tag?

Tags: tags, drupal-8

I want to remove a script tag and tried this code:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t3H05.png)

```
function mythemename_js_alter(&$javascript,AttachedAssetsInterface $assets){
unset($javascript['/public:/languages/en_QSlF4vrel7qmkEG5lSj1NjAbhdL7GHx1GMl9HN4CFmo.js']);
}
```

But the script tag is still here.

Answer (score 0):

**1.print_r($javascript);**
**2.find the js location;**
**3.unset($javascript['path of what you found']);**
**

For example :

The script src is /public:/languages/en_QSlF4vrel7qmkEG5lSj1NjAbhdL7GHx1GMl9HN4CFmo.js

I found this :

```
[core/modules/locale/locale.translation.js] =>
Array ( [group] => -100 [type] => external
[data] =>/public://languages/en_QSlF4vrel7qmkEG5lSj1NjAbhdL7GHx1GMl9HN4CFmo.js 
[version] => -1 
[minified] => 
[weight] => -17.996 
[cache] => 1 
[preprocess] => 1 
[attributes] => Array ( ) 
[browsers] => Array ( )
[scope] => footer )
```

Then use

```
unset($javascript['core/modules/locale/locale.translation.js']);
```